# mapPartitionsWithIndex giving a different header

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have some csv files such as this:

```
ç
NU_NOTIF,CoordX_UTMSAD69,CoordY_UTMSAD69,TP_NOT,ID_AGRAVO,DT_NOTIFIC,SEM_NOT,NU_ANO,SG_UF_NOT,ID_UNIDADE,DT_SIN_PRI,SEM_PRI,CS_RACA,CS_ESCOL_N,ID_CNS_SUS,NDUPLIC_N,DT_DIGITA,DT_TRANSUS,DT_TRANSDM,DT_TRANSSM,DT_TRANSRM,DT_TRANSRS,DT_TRANSSE,NU_LOTE_V,NU_LOTE_H,CS_FLXRET,FLXRECEBI,IDENT_MICR,MIGRADO_W,DT_INVEST,ID_OCUPA_N,DT_SORO,RESUL_SORO,DT_NS1,RESUL_NS1,DT_VIRAL,RESUL_VI_N,DT_PCR,RESUL_PCR_,SOROTIPO,HISTOPA_N,IMUNOH_N,DOENCA_TRA,EPISTAXE,GENGIVO,METRO,PETEQUIAS,HEMATURA,SANGRAM,LACO_N,PLASMATICO,EVIDENCIA,PLAQ_MENOR,TP_SISTEMA,Long_WGS84,Lat_WGS84
2332769,"677873,18","7468220,51",2,A90,29/01/2010 00:00:00,201004,2010,33,2273225,11/01/2010 00:00:00,201002,9,03, , ,26/02/2010 00:00:00,,,16/11/2010 00:00:00,,,,2010041, , , , , ,29/01/2010 00:00:00, ,18/01/2010 00:00:00,1,, ,,4,,4, ,4,4,2, , , , , , , , , ,0.000000000000000,1,"-43.266430481500002","-22.884869715699999"
2273294,"676608,79","7467659,4",2,A90,22/01/2010 00:00:00,201003,2010,33,2708167,21/01/2010 00:00:00,201003,9,09, , ,04/02/2010 00:00:00,,,16/11/2010 00:00:00,,,,2010041, , , , , ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,0.000000000000000,1,"-43.278688469099997","-22.890070246099999"
2446032,"669591,392118294","7467756,59464924",2,A90,15/01/2010 00:00:00,201002,2010,33,2296608,09/01/2010 00:00:00,201001,9,09, , ,15/01/2010 00:00:00,,,16/11/2010 00:00:00,,,,2010041, , , , , ,15/01/2010 00:00:00, ,,4,, ,,4,,4, ,4,4,9, , , , , , , , , ,0.000000000000000,1,"-43.347090180499997","-22.889919181600000"
```

In order to parse this skipping the first line (which I don't know why it was placed there, but there's nothing I can do), I did:

```
val csv = sc.textFile("./project/Casos_Notificados_Dengue_01_2010.csv")

val rdd = csv.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
    (i,iterator) => if (i == 0 && iterator.hasNext){
      iterator.next
      iterator
    }else iterator)
```

And using    `rdd.foreach(x => println(x.toString  + "\n" ))` to check whether the rdd was okay or not. Unfortunately, it's getting a random line as the first line  instead of the header (which I assume it should be the first line, right?).

So, the result is something like this:

```
2258026,"685693,42","7458369,42",2,A90,27/01/2010 00:00:00,201004,2010,33,3005992,25/01/2010 00:00:00,201004,9,09, , ,27/04/2010 00:00:00,,,07/12/2010 00:00:00,,,,2010049, , , , , ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,0.000000000000000,1,"-43.189041385899998","-22.972965925200000"

NU_NOTIF,CoordX_UTMSAD69,CoordY_UTMSAD69,TP_NOT,ID_AGRAVO,DT_NOTIFIC,SEM_NOT,NU_ANO,SG_UF_NOT,ID_UNIDADE,DT_SIN_PRI,SEM_PRI,CS_RACA,CS_ESCOL_N,ID_CNS_SUS,NDUPLIC_N,DT_DIGITA,DT_TRANSUS,DT_TRANSDM,DT_TRANSSM,DT_TRANSRM,DT_TRANSRS,DT_TRANSSE,NU_LOTE_V,NU_LOTE_H,CS_FLXRET,FLXRECEBI,IDENT_MICR,MIGRADO_W,DT_INVEST,ID_OCUPA_N,DT_SORO,RESUL_SORO,DT_NS1,RESUL_NS1,DT_VIRAL,RESUL_VI_N,DT_PCR,RESUL_PCR_,SOROTIPO,HISTOPA_N,IMUNOH_N,DOENCA_TRA,EPISTAXE,GENGIVO,METRO,PETEQUIAS,HEMATURA,SANGRAM,LACO_N,PLASMATICO,EVIDENCIA,PLAQ_MENOR,TP_SISTEMA,Long_WGS84,Lat_WGS84

2258019,"686278,41","7459234,58",2,A90,18/01/2010 00:00:00,201003,2010,33,3005992,16/01/2010 00:00:00,201002,9,09, , ,22/01/2010 00:00:00,,,16/11/2010 00:00:00,,,,2010041, , , , , ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,0.000000000000000,1,"-43.183441365699998","-22.965089100099998"

2332769,"677873,18","7468220,51",2,A90,29/01/2010 00:00:00,201004,2010,33,2273225,11/01/2010 00:00:00,201002,9,03, , ,26/02/2010 00:00:00,,,16/11/2010 00:00:00,,,,2010041, , , , , ,29/01/2010 00:00:00, ,18/01/2010 00:00:00,1,, ,,4,,4, ,4,4,2, , , , , , , , , ,0.000000000000000,1,"-43.
```

Does anyone know how to put the header on the first line?
Also, is there any way to get just some columns of the csv using the mapPartitionsWithIndex?

**EDIT 1**

As @user3712791 stated, It lacked a **true** after the `}else iterator), so, for now it's going well.

```
val csv = sc.textFile("./project/Casos_Notificados_Dengue_01_2010.csv")

val rdd = csv.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
    (i,iterator) => if (i == 0 && iterator.hasNext){
      iterator.next
      iterator
    }else iterator),true)
```

@Paul, I misunderstood what mapPartitionsWithIndex does. I thought it did like a key-values with the header and the data (rows above the header).

I believe now I have to do a groupBy to achieve this or is there any other better idea to do so?

(I have to do this because I just need 5 columns from the data)

Comment: mapPartitionsWithIndex doesn't do what I think you think it does. It runs map on each partition, passing also the index of the _partition_, not the index of the element in the RDD. So you're skipping the first line of partition 0, which isn't necessarily the first part of the file.

Comment: @paul I think this is probably not a bad approach provided this is the first operation. The partitions that come back from textfile are generally in order so skipping the first line of partition 0 should be fine.

Comment: "generally in order" worries me. And the OP's results show it is NOT fine? ("it's getting a random line as the first line instead of the header ")

Comment: foreach is the part that eveluates multiple partitions and not in a defined order.

Comment: I assume "random line as the first line" means the header line still turned up in the foreach (and you can see this in the output).  The code should discard the header line, if it's working as the OP intends (and you claim "should" or "generally" work) before the foreach is called. So if the header line appears in the output of the foreach, the idea of dropping the first line of partition 0 is s not working.

Comment: In this case it looks like there _might_ be too header lines that the OP needs to discard unless there was a cut and paste error in the input data.

Comment: Ah, good spot. Let's wait for the OP to confirm

Comment: It seems like I couldn't explain good enough the problem. 
The line that I wanted to skip was the "ç" line and preserve the rest, specially the header `NU_NOTIF,CoordX_UTMSAD69,CoordY_UTMSAD69...`. Although, while using the code, it just got some lines and put before this. But as stated by @user3712791, it lacked a true after the `}else iterator),true).

Now it just does what I wanted to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the mapWithIndex in a RDD isn't fixed if the parameter preservesPartitioning is not set.

So add after the function a ,true and it should work... Like:

```
val csv = sc.textFile("./project/Casos_Notificados_Dengue_01_2010.csv")

val rdd = csv.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
    ((i,iterator) => if (i == 0 && iterator.hasNext){
      iterator.next
      iterator
    }else iterator), true)
```

For the new info: I think it's already a whole new question but...
First you're taking a text file and putting it in a RDD it will be an RDD of strings, so you probably will not be able to use a GroupBy...

First let's make a schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schemaArray = csv.collect()(0).split(",")
val schema =
  StructType(
    schemaArray.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
```

Now that we have an schema... It's as simple as the tutorial goes, but i will write it here:

```
val rowRDD = rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row.fromSeq(p))

// Apply the schema to the RDD.
val schemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)

// Register the SchemaRDD as a table.
schemaRDD.registerTempTable("casos")

// SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext.
val results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5 FROM casos")

// The results of SQL queries are SchemaRDDs and support all the normal RDD operations.
// The columns of a row in the result can be accessed by ordinal.
results.map(t => "Column1: " + t(0)).collect().foreach(println)
//You may also want to refine the new object somehow
results.registerTempTable("tempTable")
val results2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5 FROM casos WHERE Column1=1")
```

I may have forgotten some import,so i will leave here the link to the tutorial: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#rdds

Comment: I think the partitions order on the input will be the same, looking at MapPartitionsRDD getPartitions function always uses the parents partition so the partition index should remain constant.

Comment: It should stay the same... But neverthless they allow the function to change the keys, and so change the ordering. The problem is that it doesn't guarantee that the order remains constant... Setting preservesPartitioning = true makes it guaranteed that the ordering stays constant.
The catch is if your function changes ordering this will raise an error and if order doesn't matter you don't need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

So for your specific task I'd suggest looking at the spark-csv package on http://spark-packages.org . If you end up having to do the parsing by hand, you might just want to call `first()` to get the first line.

The other option is you could do this similar to how CsvRleation in spark-csv works which is grabbing the first line and then filtering out that line if it shows up anywhere:

```
  /**
   * Returns the first line of the first non-empty file in path
   */
  private lazy val firstLine = {
    // Using Spark to read the first line to be able to handle all Hadoop input (gz, bz, etc.)
    sqlContext.sparkContext.textFile(location).first()
  }
  rdd.filter(_ != firstLine)
```

Comment: first() is exactly what the OP doesn't want. The OP wants to discard the first line, not get it.

Comment: Paul: the OP was asking how to check what was going, and first() will show them the first line.

Comment: And how does that help?

Comment: Well if they want to check that the first line doesn't contain the header, getting the first line back to the driver to print out seems like it would be useful. As for solving the csv parsing problem in general, the OPs current approach seems _ok_ and I've also suggested a package the OP can use if they choose.

Comment: The OP knows the first line of the file is the header. And so the first element of the csv RDD is the header. The problem is how to return an RDD that is csv.tail, if that operation existed. Not to retrieve that first line.

Comment: Paul if the OP calls first on the RDD _after_ filtering out the header line then the OP will be able to see if the header has been filtered.

Comment: The OP knows it has not! See the output given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78476/discussion-between-holden-and-paul).